# MouseDown event not fireing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events

I want to add option to draw rectangle on image. But that is not problem.
In order to get it working I need to use MouseDown, MouseUp and MouseLeave events of Image Control in WPF.

```
    <DockPanel Name="dockPanel1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15">
        <GroupBox Header="WebCam" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid>
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Name="pictureBoxMain" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinHeight="240" MinWidth="320" StretchDirection="DownOnly" MaxWidth="960" MaxHeight="1200" MouseDown="pictureBoxMain_MouseDown" MouseUp="pictureBoxMain_MouseUp" MouseLeave="pictureBoxMain_MouseLeave" Panel.ZIndex="50" />
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="stackPanel2" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="15,0,0,0">
            <GroupBox Header="Controls" Name="groupBox2">
                <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1">
                    <Button Content="Start" Height="23" Name="buttonStartStop" Width="120" Margin="0" Click="buttonStartStop_Click" />
                    <Button Content="Video Properties" Height="23" Name="buttonVideoProperties" Width="120" Margin="0" Click="buttonVideoProperties_Click" />
                    <Button Content="WebCam Settings" Height="23" Name="buttonWebCamSettings" Width="120" Margin="0" Click="buttonWebCamSettings_Click" />
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="Motion Data" Name="groupBox3">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="Strength: 0" x:Name="labelMotionStrength" />
                    <Label Content="Count: 0" x:Name="timesWasMotionCounter" />
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
```

I'm talking about events of "pictureBoxMain".
Why those events never fire? I'm clicking on my image like crazy and still nothing.
What should I do to make those event working?

Comment: Try handling PreviewMouseDown instead (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858539/image-mousedown-event-not-firing)

Comment: @Surfbutler still not working.

Comment: Try putting the mouse handlers on the parent Grid, and give the Grid a Background property of "Transparent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error.
For some reason my picture box size was 0,0.
I stretched it and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried catching PreviewMouseDown?

```
To capture the same as MouseDown you need to use PreviewMouseDown event which is a tunneling event.
```

Comment: PreviewMouseDown does not fire also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Source attribute of the Image to an image file or binding before the event handlers will work:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Name="pictureBoxMain" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinHeight="240" MinWidth="320" StretchDirection="DownOnly" MaxWidth="960" MaxHeight="1200" MouseDown="pictureBoxMain_MouseDown" MouseUp="pictureBoxMain_MouseUp" MouseLeave="pictureBoxMain_MouseLeave" Source="test_image.png" Panel.ZIndex="50" />
```

Comment: I use picture box to display webcam video frames. Images are asigned later in code. But it still does not work image assign to it.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you assign the image in code?  If I assign a value to pictureBoxMain.Source in the buttonStartStop_Click event handler instead of in the XAML, it works fine.

Comment: BitmapSource bmaps = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitMap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()); bmaps.Freeze(); pictureBoxMain.Source = bmaps;        This works fine. Only events are not fired.